# How do I get/check if carbon wheels are tubeless compatible

Tags: tubeless, zipp, tubular

I have fake Zipp 404 and Continental GP4000 SII tubular on it. It is time to change it.

The question is how do I know if this wheels

- a) without removing
- b) with removing

tubeless compatible or not?

[image: tubular]

Comment: Not a dupe, but here's a question/answer on replacing tubulars. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/66548/19705   You need tape or glue, and about 3 days total.   And ways to remove the old glue from the rim.

Comment: @Criggie My friends tell me they exchange spare pre-glued tubulars mid-race faster than they would exchange a tube. I have no personal experience though.

Comment: @VladimirF Noone changes tubular tyres in a race.  They would absolutely swap a wheel out from the team car or neutral service support though.  Using the proper tape is quicker than glue, but it still has to sit under pressure for a while to set up

Comment: @Criggie There is no such support in those amateur triathlon races. And no teams, the less team cars. They do indeed swap tubulars. Check, for example, https://forum.slowtwitch.com/forum/Slowtwitch_Forums_C1/Triathlon_Forum_F1/Spare_tubular_tire_to_carry_during_a_race_P6939708/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tubular rims are never compatible with tubeless tires.

Tubular rims have a slightly concave bed that the tire sits on. Tubeless tires are a variation on clincher tires, and require sidewalls to retain the tire bead.

[image: rim type comparison]

Comment: Concur - Second way to test is deflate the tube, and gently lever the tyre up.  If it is glued or taped to the rim, its a tubular and you can only replace it with another tubular tyre.   If the rims are known-fakes then the tyre could be too.